# How should I answer a question "on behalf of"?

Tags: support, answers, comments

I know that answering questions in a comment is bad, but I am grateful to many people for driving me in the right direction, even with a comment ([recent case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71518103/how-can-i-declare-a-struct-of-maps-as-a-global-variable)).

Is there a way to answer a question on behalf of a user ("out of gratitude") so that the answer can be accepted and upvoted?

I usually kindly ask a commenter to just bootstrap an answer (literally just copy/paste their comment) and I would be glad to complete it (edit) with a description, links, etc. to make it a complete answer. Sometimes it works, sometimes not.

I abhor the idea of creating the answer from the comment myself, as it is not something I invented in the first place (I know this can be a community wiki, but I still would like to give rep where it is due).

Comment: No, as that'd be leaving said user on the hook for something they didn't create.

Comment: @KevinB: I thought about that too, ideally there could be a cooldown period during which someone can reject the answer in their name - but I guess it would be too complex

Comment: the most "correct" way would be to simply answer it yourself while giving them proper attribution. CW if you want... but the purpose of CW isn't not earning rep, so if that's why you're using it... you're misusing it.

Comment: If they didn't want it to post as an answer then don't force them. Just use that comment to create your own answer. If you don't want reputation, mark it as CW. That's it.

Answer (score 11):

There is no such feature.

If the user does not to want to post an answer, one cannot force them to, nor do it for them.

The way to give credit to another user is to give [attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) where is due.

If you feel bad about getting reputation for that answer, just make it a Community Wiki, as you mention. Or just wait it out and let someone else do it.

Comment: My rule of thumb is, if you're *building on* the comment, turning it into a fleshed-out answer, then you should *not* mark it as CW, just give attribution to the original author of the comment. If *all* you're doing is reposting the comment as an answer (essentially, manually "promoting" the comment to an answer, since there is no system tooling for this), then I would mark it as a CW. It is not technically required for you to *ever* mark it as CW, but the above is the guideline I follow and would recommend.